# Finding the amount of children in a list

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to find a way to get the children of a list. I have tried different ways but can never get the correct amount. I get the amount of total children instead of the amount of children for the specific clicked value. Here is an example code:

```
<li class="category">First
 <ul style="display: none;">
    <li class="category_sub">1</li>
    <li class="category_sub">2</li>
    <li class="category_sub">3</li>
 </ul>
</li>
<li class="category">Second
 <ul style="display: none;">
    <li class="category_sub">1</li>
    <li class="category_sub">2</li>
    <li class="category_sub">3</li>
    <li class="category_sub">4</li>
 </ul>
</li>
<li class="category">Third
 <ul style="display: none;">
    <li class="category_sub">1</li>
    <li class="category_sub">2</li>
    <li class="category_sub">3</li>
    <li class="category_sub">4</li>
    <li class="category_sub">5</li>
 </ul>
</li>
```

Here is Javascript:

```
      $('.category').click(function(){
        if($(this).hasClass('active')){
            $('.category').removeClass('hide');
            $(this).removeClass('active');
            $(this).parent().find("ul").hide();
        }else if(!$(this).hasClass('active') && !$(this).hasClass('hide')){
            $('.category').addClass('hide');
            $(this).removeClass('hide');
            $(this).addClass('active');
            $(this).parent().find("ul").toggle();
            $(this).parent().find("ul").css({"padding-top":"15px"});
            alert($(this).parent().find('ul').children().length); 
        }
    });
```

Here is some CSS:

```
.category_sub{
  list-style-type: none;
  width: 100%;
  padding-left: 20px;
  height: 40px;
}

.category_sub:hover{
  background-color: #aaa;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.category{
  list-style-type: none;
  width: 100%;
  padding-left: 0px;
  height: 40px;
  color: black;
}

.category.hide{
 display: none;
}

.category.active{
  background-color: #aaa;
}
```

Here is a Jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/1svvm69r/

Now when I click on first, I expect to see 3 but I get 12. It is counting all the children and not the value clicked. If you look at the JS you will see I am alerting the method to get the value. Any suggestions?

Comment: use this alert($(this).find('ul li') .length);  you are selecting parent.so wats happening here is jquery will find the parent of  li with class .category that is parent ul which contains all your lists and inner ul's.so u are getting all the lists.to avoid just use current li to find all lists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line:

```
$(this).parent().find('ul')
```

executes the following actions:

1. Find the parent of the `.category` element.
2. Obtain a collection of all the `ul` elements that are children of the parent of the `.category` element.

That is the reason it returns `12` instead of `3`. What you want to do is find the `ul` for the element and not its parent:

`$(this).find('ul')`

Answer (score 1):

Correct the alert statement to

```
alert($(this).children().find('li').length);
```

`.children()` will get the `ul` element and then you can use `find()` to fetch all the `li` elements within it.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are setting an active class, you could simply make it yourself a bit easier, and just count all the li's of the .active category like this

```
alert($('.category.active > ul > li').length);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just do the following :

```
        $('.category').click(function(){
        if($(this).hasClass('active')){
            $('.category').removeClass('hide');
            $(this).removeClass('active');
            $(this).parent().find("ul").hide();
        }else if(!$(this).hasClass('active') && !$(this).hasClass('hide')){
            $('.category').addClass('hide');
            $(this).removeClass('hide');
            $(this).addClass('active');
            $(this).parent().find("ul").toggle();
            $(this).parent().find("ul").css({"padding-top":"15px"});
        }
        alert($(this).find('li').length); 
    });
```